# How to index new document in elasticsearch using term_vector?

Tags: java, mongodb, elasticsearch

I'm trying to implement application that get document from MongoDB and insert it to ElasticSearch. Here is a piece of code that should insert document to the ElasticSearch index:

```java
final Document o = (Document) document.get("o"); // this is where object lives
client.prepareIndex(index, mapping, id.toString())
    .setSource(o.toJson())
    .execute().actionGet();
```

And finally I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mapper for [title] conflicts with existing mapping in other types:
>   [mapper [title] has different [store_term_vector] values, mapper [title] has different [store_term_vector_offsets] values, mapper [title] has different [store_term_vector_positions] values, mapper [title] has different [store_term_vector_payloads] values]
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.FieldTypeLookup.checkCompatibility(FieldTypeLookup.java:117)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.checkNewMappersCompatibility(MapperService.java:368)
>       at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.merge(MapperService.java:319)

I'v tried to remove index completely using XDELETE and recreate using XPUT and error remain.

Here is how my index settings look like:

```
{
  "msg": {
    "mappings": {
      "Message": {
        "properties": {
          "title": {
            "type": "string",
            "term_vector": "with_positions_offsets_payloads",
            "analyzer": "russian"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However if I remove this `term_vector` part from index settings the code is inserts new document successfully.

Can someone explain me what is the problem? The same problem occur when I'm trying to use mongo-connector. If `settings` contain `term_vector` part for **title** field => mongo-connector fails with same Exception. And it works well without `term_vector`.

Comment: @Brook B:  I saw that too, but then I saw an example in the term_vectors documentation  that uses with_positions_offsets_payloads.  At any rate, I copied and pasted that mapping into Sense and I was able to insert a document into the index just fine.  Try deleting the index, creating the mapping, and inserting the doc in Sense and see if it works.  If it does, maybe the problem is with whatever client API you're using, or how you're using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope my answer will help someone else.

The problem was that I have another mapping in the same index that also have field `title`. You have to update all other mappings to use same settings.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are using the correct `term_vector` value? I am only aware of five valid values for that attribute, [as listed in the documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/term-vector.html):

> Possible values are `no`, `yes`, `with_offsets`, `with_positions`, `with_positions_offsets`. Defaults to `no`.

I would suggest trying a different `term_vector` such as `with_positions_offsets` to see if you get the results you're expecting.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was in other mappings